# React Bootstrap OverlayTrigger not rearranging after popover content changes

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have an issue when refreshing the content of a Popover using the OverlayTrigger. Basically, what I would expect is that if the content changes, the OverlayTrigger rearranges its position. But it doesn't.

Given the following code, that can be seen here: https://codesandbox.io/s/W6pDkDoyW

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Popover, OverlayTrigger } from 'react-bootstrap';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      names: ['george'],
    };
    this.loadMore = this.loadMore.bind(this);
    this.setOld = this.setOld.bind(this);
  }

  loadMore() {
    const _this = this;
    setTimeout(() => {
      _this.setState({ names: ['george', 'steve', 'peter'] });
    }, 500);
  }

  setOld() {
    this.setState({ names: ['george'] });
  }

  render() {
    const popover = (
      <Popover id="test-popover">
        {this.state.names.map((n, index) =>
          <p key={index}>
            {n}
          </p>,
        )}
      </Popover>
    );

    return (
      <OverlayTrigger
        trigger={['hover', 'focus']}
        placement="top"
        overlay={popover}
        onEnter={this.loadMore}
        onExit={this.setOld}
      >
        <span>This is a div</span>
      </OverlayTrigger>
    );
  }
}

const Container = () => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        minHeight: '24em',
      }}
    >
      <div style={{ maxWidth: '50%' }}>
        <App />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

render(<Container />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[image: This is when the popover is hovered initially]

[image: This is what happens when the popover is refreshed while being hovered]

Is this possible or not?